# How many state configurations are possible for $N$ particles in completely different states?

Tags: thermodynamics, probability

How many state configurations are possible for $N$ particles in completely different states?

I cannot remember if the total number of state configurations for $N$ particles in completely different states is $n^n$ or $n!$.

Also, if $n$ particles are in completely different states, does this represent the maximum possible entropy of this system?

Comment: How many 'completely different states' are available?

Comment: Oh I forgot about that. I was thinking of only $N$ available states for $N$ particles. However, it might be more appropriate to ask about $M$ available states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $N$ particles that can occupy $M$ different states $\left(M\geq N\right)$, it seems to me that the answer is $$M\cdot M-1 \cdot \dots \cdot M-(N-1)=M!/(M-N)!\ $$ if one imposes that each must occupy a different state.

That is since, to the first particle, $M$ states are available. For the second, $M-1$. We continue thus until we run out of particles, the last one having a choice from $M-(N-1)$ states. It is $N-1$ since the first particle could choose from $M-0=M$ states, and not $M-1$.

Comment: Does this represent the maximum entropy?

Comment: @linuxfreebird I am reluctant to answer this since entropy is both observer-dependent and generally misleading, but I'd say that this actually represents a relatively low entropy configuration, since all particles are distinguishable. This all depends on 'the rules of the game' too: Maybe only different states are allowed? Then there is no way to make the entropy go up, of course...